# SQL - How to Order By in UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to union two tables, but keep the rows from the first table appearing first in the result set? However orderby column is not in select query

For example:

Table 1

```
name        surname
-------------------
John         Doe
Bob          Marley
Ras          Tafari
```

Table 2

```
name       surname
------------------
Lucky      Dube
Abby       Arnold
Result
```

Expected Result:

```
name        surname
-------------------
John         Doe
Bob          Marley 
Ras          Tafari
Lucky      Dube
Abby       Arnold
```

I am bringing Data by following query

```
SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 1 ORDER BY ID  
UNION  
SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 2
```

The above query is not keeping track of order by after union.
P.S - I dont want to show ID in my select query
I am getting ORDER BY Column by joining tables. Following is my real query

```
  SELECT tbl_Event_Type_Sort_Orders.Appraisal_Event_Type_ID AS Appraisal_Event_Type_ID , ISNULL(tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types.Appraisal_Event_Type_Display_Name, 'UnCategorized') AS  Appraisal_Event_Type_Display_Name 
INTO #temptbl
FROM tbl_Event_Type_Sort_Orders 
INNER JOIN tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types
ON tbl_Event_Type_Sort_Orders.Appraisal_Event_Type_ID = tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types.Appraisal_Event_Type_ID
WHERE 1=1
AND User_Name='abc' 
ORDER BY tbl_Event_Type_Sort_Orders.Sort_Order

SELECT * FROM #temptbl 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT (tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types.Appraisal_Event_Type_ID) AS Appraisal_Event_Type_ID , ISNULL(tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types.Appraisal_Event_Type_Display_Name, 'UnCategorized') AS  Appraisal_Event_Type_Display_Name 
FROM tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types
INNER JOIN tbl_Appraisal_Events
ON tbl_Appraisal_Event_Types.Appraisal_Event_Type_ID = tbl_Appraisal_Events.Event_Type_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Appraisals 
ON tbl_Appraisal_Events.Appraisal_ID = tbl_Appraisal_Events.Appraisal_ID
WHERE 1=1
AND ((tbl_Appraisals.Assigned_To_Staff_User) = 'abc'  OR (tbl_Appraisals.Assigned_To_Staff_User2) = 'abc' OR (tbl_Appraisals.Assigned_To_Staff_User3) = 'abc')
```

Comment: what relevance has the html code got to do with your SQL query?

Comment: You know that you produce results² ?

Comment: it should work ``SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 1 UNION  SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 2 ORDER BY ID``

Comment: And if the same person exists in both tables?

Comment: Add Bob Marley to first table. And also add Abby Arnold to first table. Then adjust the result.

Comment: @jarlh It has to be shown once at that case, i guess that is what UNION does

Comment: Yes, but for table1 or for table2?

Comment: @jarlh for table1

Comment: I have updated my question with real query i am using. I am bringing Order by column by joining tables. I want 'Order By' to be set only on table 1 and then join rest of the data from table2 to table 1 which is not present in table 1

Comment: As jarlh sais: `UNION` is there to eliminated duplicates (otherwise you'd simply use `UNION ALL`). So you want all records from table1 sorted followed by all table2 records unordered. But once you `UNION` the data sets there is no longer a table1 or table2 record; each record shown can be in one of the tables or both. What to do when the record is in both tables? (Or are you using `UNION mistakenly` and actually want to use `UNION ALL`?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a `UNION ALL` in a derived table. To keep duplicate elimination, do `select distinct` and also add a `NOT EXISTS` to second select to avoid returning same person twice if found in both tables:

```
select name, surname
from
(
    select distinct name, surname, 1 as tno
    from table1
    union all
    select distinct name, surname, 2 as tno
    from table2 t2
    where not exists (select * from table1 t1
                      where t2.name = t1.name
                        and t2.surname = t1.surname)
) dt
order by tno, surname, name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a column for the table and one for the ID to order by:

```
SELECT x.name, x.surname FROM (
    SELECT ID, TableID = 1, name, surname
    FROM table1

    UNION  ALL

    SELECT ID = -1, TableID = 2, name, surname
    FROM table2
) x
ORDER BY x.TableID, x.ID
```

Comment: I'm curious: why do you have `ID = -1` in the second part of the `union`?

Comment: Because i thought that the second table shouldn't be sorted by id and i needed a value

Answer (score 0):

You can write as below, if you are ok with duplicate data then please use UNION ALL it will be faster:

```
SELECT NAME, surname FROM (
SELECT ID,name,surname FROM TABLE 1 
UNION
SELECT ID,name,surname FROM TABLE 2 ) t ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: I think the op wants to keep the rows from the first table first. in that case something like `SELECT NAME, surname FROM (
SELECT ID,name,surname FROM TABLE 1 
UNION
SELECT 999999999,name,surname FROM TABLE 2 ) t ORDER BY ID`

Answer (score 0):

simply use a `UNION` clause with out `order by`.

```
   SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 1 
   UNION
   SELECT name,surname FROM TABLE 2
```

if you wanted to order first table use the below query.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
 (SELECT name,surname,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY  Id)b FROM TABLE 1 )
SELECT name,surname
FROM cte_1
UNION 
SELECT name,surname 
FROM TABLE 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this will order the first row sets first then by anything you need
(haven't tested the code)

```
;with cte_1
as 
 (SELECT ID,name,surname,1 as table_id FROM TABLE 1 
  UNION
  SELECT ID,name,surname,2 as table_id FROM TABLE 2 ) 
SELECT name, surname 
FROM cte_1
ORDER BY table_id,ID
```

Comment: Table is a reserved word. Also, this is not a union anymore.